# SDK Flex 3.4.0.9271A, Adobe Flex 122MB

Tags: apache-flex, sdk, air, adobe

If any of you has zip package of SDK Flex 3.4.0.9271A (122MB), please share.

I found source link here https://sourceforge.net/adobe/flexsdk/wiki/Download%20Flex%203/ but this version is not found on server.

I also need AdobeAIR SDK 1.5.2 package, which is not available here https://helpx.adobe.com/pl/air/kb/archived-air-sdk-version.html

The requested URL /pub/flex/sdk/builds/flex3/flex_sdk_3.4.0.9271A&pkgtype=1 was not found on this server.

I found only version 3.4.1.10084A
here:
https://joshblog.net/2014/download-legacy-adobe-flex-sdk-versions/

Comment: I don't understand this place, a few second after question someone give minus on question, fear to ask anything here - so much hate :/ ... why?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your question is pretty clearly offtopic (asking for an offsite download).  You'll get better results asking sourceforge about the missing file.

Comment: Ok, I will ask them, but I'm sure that they will ignore my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why did you want the old version?

**[EDIT]**
I found this: **http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flex/sdk/builds/flex3/flex_sdk_3.4.0.9271A.zip**

when I checked using CURL -sI , last modified was on 28 July 2011. This is might the one you were looking for?

```
curl -sI http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flex/sdk/builds/flex3/flex_sdk_3.4.0.9271A.zip
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Thu, 28 Jul 2011 18:19:25 GMT
ETag: "77db4fe-4a9253468a540"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 125678846
Content-Type: application/zip
Date: Thu, 21 Jun 2018 04:54:55 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: I have to make some changes in very old AIR application, I have a lot of problems with compilation and other things, I have to do it because last programmer who makes some changes in this app don't want to help me. I found there info about what SDK was used last time on this. So I want to recreate the environment to make sure that all problems are not related with SDK. This is why I look this specified version :(.

Comment: Is this the link you are trying to download?
Its still there anyway!
http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flex/sdk/builds/flex3/flex_sdk_3.4.0.9271A.zip

Comment: When I checked using CURL I got this, tlast-modified was on Thu, 28 Jul 2011 18:19:25 GMT. May be this is the one you were looking for?
`curl -sI http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flex/sdk/builds/flex
3/flex_sdk_3.4.0.9271A.zip`
`HTTP/1.1 200 OK`
`Server: Apache`
`Last-Modified: Thu, 28 Jul 2011 18:19:25 GMT`
`ETag: "77db4fe-4a9253468a540"`
`Accept-Ranges: bytes`
`Content-Length: 125678846`
`Content-Type: application/zip`
`Date: Thu, 21 Jun 2018 04:54:55 GMT`
`Connection: keep-alive`

Comment: Yes, this is the one what I'm looking for. Thank you very much for your help.